# flask_sock giving error as ConnectionError. Need start stop socket data button functionality on flask app

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I have python flask app with that i am using flask_sock to send continuous data from app server to UI. I am opening this socket from html JavaScript client. I need start stop button on UI for this socket. But as soon as i call method on socket.close() from JavaScript client my python app crashes with error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2532, in wsgi_app
    return response(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sock\__init__.py", line 83, in __call__
    raise ConnectionError()
ConnectionError
```

My python app server side code for socket is -

```
from flask_sock import Sock

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
sock = Sock(app)

@sock.route('/startDataWS')
def startDataWS(ws):
    while True:
        #data = ws.receive()
        data = TManager.getDataForUI()
        ws.send(json.dumps(data))
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

My Client side javascript code is -

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + "localhost:8080" + '/startOptionChainWS');
 
function startSocketClickHandler() {           
  socket.addEventListener('message', ev => {
    const objData = JSON.parse(ev.data);
    parseOptionChainData(objData);       
  });
};

function stopSocketClickHandler(){
  socket.close();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Werkzeug (the web server used by Flask in development mode) is not very good at dealing with WebSocket routes. You can try upgrading Flask and Werkzeug to their latest releases and that might help.

In any case, when you run your application in production using Gunicorn you will not see this error.